# res.redirect() cors not working in MEAN app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, redirect, cors

I have a MEAN APP with Angular 5 and I am trying to redirect a user to a external URL but I don't know why i get the next two errors in console

> - Failed to load https://www.google.com.ar/: No
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>     resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>     access.
> - Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

I already enabled CORS but still doesn't work

**Component Angular 5**

```
this.http.get('/api/producto').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

**APP.JS**

```
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('./config/database');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/producto', cors(), function (req, res) {
  res.status(301).redirect("https://www.google.com.ar")
  res.end();
})

app.use(compression());

mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(config.database, { promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
  .then(() => console.log('connection succesful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'false' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

If I go to "http://localhost:3000/api/producto" the redirecting works perfectly but if the component calls the api it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: I already read that post and I enable CORS but still doesn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is your component using the Angular HTTP module to make an ajax request?

Comment: Im using this modules:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

Answer (score 4):

Your code may not be doing what you want, but is working correctly. Even if you use cors on your backend, the response you send `/api/producto` is a redirection to google.

When angular makes the calls, it gets the redirection to google as a response. The front end then tries an ajax request to google, which does not have the CORS headers (only your back end response had the CORS headers).

If you want to redirect the user to google, your backend needs to return the url with status code 200, and then in your front end you can redirect the url

```
this.http.get('/api/producto').subscribe(url=> {
  window.location.href = url;
 });
```

Comment: This is not possible if your url contains secure parameters, such as API secrets